# Dirichlet's formula for the number of ideals of a given norm in a quadratic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $R(m)$ be the number of ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ of norm $m$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, for $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. I have read that

> $R(m) = \sum_{n \mid m, n > 0} \left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ [...] by Dirichlet's factorization of the zeta-function for $K$ [This is from Gross and Zagier's *On Singular Moduli*].

where I assume that $\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol. Does anyone have a reference for how to derive this from the zeta-function for $K$. It seems that there are direct arguments using unique factorization of ideals, but I would like to improve my skills with analytic tools.

Comment: The factorization being referred to is $\zeta_K(s) = \zeta(s) L(s,\chi_{-p})$, where $\chi_{-p}(n) = (\frac np)$ is the Dirichlet character that is also the Legendre symbol. Is this the missing fact that you needed, or do you know this already and are wondering why it gives the desired conclusion?

Comment: I did not know what factorization they were referring to, but it is also not obvious to me how this gives the desired conclusion (my command of L-functions is rudimentary), so if there is an elegant argument I would love to hear it!

Comment: The key "Dirichlet convolution" identity is that $( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} )( \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s} ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}$ where $c_n = \sum_{d\mid n,\, d>0} a_d b_{n/d}$. This material would be given in a source that teaches Dirichlet series (for example, Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I*).